# Conditional URL rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need the URL `example.com/app` to show the content from `example.com/app/dist`

The following code does exactly this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /app/dist/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dist/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/dist/$1
```

BUT I also need the URL `example.com/staging` to show the content from `example.com/staging/dist`

With the current setup, the url `example.com/staging` is showing the content from `example.com/app/dist`

The .htaccess while is located in the `/app` and `/staging` folder (but it has to be the same file)

Comment: Is this htaccess file in the "app" folder?

Comment: @JonLin yes, updated the question too.

Answer (score 2):

In the htaccess file in your staging folder, change all instances of `app` to `staging`

Edit:
You can try using relative paths instead of hardcoding the app or staging, but Ive had issues in the past, especially if there are other rules in play.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^dist -  [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^$ dist/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
```

The idea is to remove the leading / from rewrites so a relative path is used. So technically it wont matter whatever folder the htaccess file is in

Comment: That would work, but is there a way to solve it so that the files in both folders are identical? Maybe with an if statement?

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!